# Change home folder case/name

Tags: macos

Just got a new mac and I've just realised that my name is all lower case, having a little OCD I must rectify this so that my name has the first character capitalised.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to have a working backup before performing this.

1. [Enable root user](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1528), log out of your account and log in to the root account.
2. In System Preferences, delete your account by selecting it and clicking the **-** button.
3. Select to not change your home folder.

   [image]
4. Go to `/Users` in Finder and rename the account folder how you wish (deleting the account should have appended `(Deleted)` to the name - remove this).
5. Create a new account in System Preferences as Administrator with a short name matching the renamed home folder.
6. When informed that the home folder already exists, select to use the existing home folder.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can change your user name very easily just going to **`Applications -> System Preferences -> Users & Groups`**...

If you want to change the name of your computer in your network as well, you should go to **`Applications -> System Preferences -> Sharing`**...

But, if what you want is to change your account name (i.e., the name of your home folder), that's a bit more complex. According to [this article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1428), you could do this workaround (Mac OS X v10.5 or later):

> 1. Enable the root user.
> 2. Log in as root.
> 3. Navigate to the /Users folder.
> 4. Select the Home folder with the short name you want to change, and rename it just like you would rename any folder. Keep in mind that the
>      account name must be all lowercase, with no spaces, contain only
>      letters or contain a mix of letters and numbers, and it cannot be the
>      same as an existing user's Full Name.
> 5. Use the Users & Groups pane (Accounts pane in Mac OS X v10.6.8 or earlier) in System Preferences to create a new user with the Account
>      name or Short Name that you used in the previous step.
> 6. Click OK when "A folder in the Users folder already has the name 'account name'. Would you like to use that folder as the Home folder
>      for this user account?" appears. Note: This will correct the ownership
>      of all files in the Home folder, and avoid permissions issues with the
>      contents.
> 7. Choose Log Out from the Apple menu.
> 8. Log in as the newly created user. You should be able to access all of your original files (on the desktop, in Documents, and in the other
>      folders of this Home).
> 9. After verifying that your data is as expected, you can delete the original user account via the Users & Groups pane (Accounts pane in
>      Mac OS X v10.6.8 or earlier).
> 10. Disable the root user.